# Generic Method to Get Optional Item from Map

Tags: java, generics

In Java 8, I'm trying to define a generic method to look up whether a `Map<K, V>` contains a `K key`:

```
private static Optional<V> find(final Map<K, V> map, final K key) {
    final V result = map.get(key);
    return (result == null) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(key);
}
```

But I get a bunch of compile-time errors on `K` and `V`:

```
[ERROR] ... Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ~/App.java:[31,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class K
[ERROR] location: class com.myapp.app.App
[ERROR] ~/App.java:[31,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class V
[ERROR] location: class com.myapp.app.App
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Looks like I forgot the `private static <K, V> ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static <K, V> Optional<V> find(final Map<K, V> map, final K key) {
    final V result = map.get(key);
    return Optional.ofNullable(result);
}
```

Credit - [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) for mentioning `Option#ofNullable` and my failure to list generic parameters.